# How to return status message to form [PHP]

Tags: php

So, in my corePHP Project I have `sign-up.php` page with form:

```
<form method="POST" action="./Controllers/RegistrationController.php">
```

Now, in this `RegistrationController.php` I have

```
$errors=Validator::validateUser($data);
if(count($errors)==0)
{
    //here I will add code to insert user to database later
    
}
else{
    // What code to write here?
}
```

Basically, if `array of $errors` is empty, data is valid, and user will be inserted into db, otherwise errors will be displayed on `sign-up.php` page.
My question is how to return these `$errors` to `sign-up.php` and show them in my starting form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect user to your `sign-up.php` with sending HTTP-header. Just use [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for this.

You can set your errors as query params, like `http://example.com/sign-up.php?error[field]=name&error[message]=empty!`

And for generate beautiful params, try to use [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

In your case:

```php
$errors=Validator::validateUser($data);
if(count($errors)==0)
{
    // some success things
}
else{
    // I just put all array as params for example
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/?' . http_build_query($errors));
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: That's it. Can you just help me how to delete those queries when I reload this page again?

Comment: @Lube you can place some flags like `is_error_msg = true` in cookie, and check this flags in request. Or you can using javascript for this check.